# Resolving undefined references with MySQL C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, g++, mysql-connector

I'm trying to compile this (also listed in the mysql c++ connector documentation): http://pastebin.com/HLv4zR0r

But I get these errors: http://pastebin.com/3t0UbeFy

This is how I tried compiling:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -I./include/cppconn -L./lib -lmysqlcppconn-static
```

The result of running `mysql_config --cflags --libs` is:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing  -g
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
```

Edit:

After running Jonathan Wakely's suggested command with properly-ordered linker arguments,

```
g++ -o test test.cpp  -I./include/cppconn -L./lib -lmysqlcppconn-static `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

I get different errors: http://pastebin.com/4EWNgy9i

Answer (score 0):

The mysqlcppcon library depends on the mysqlclient C libraries, so you need to put the mysqlclient libs *after* `-lmysqlcppconn-static`

```
g++ -o test test.cpp  -I./include/cppconn -L./lib -lmysqlcppconn-static `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

The order of linker arguments matters.  The linker looks at each file in order and decides if it needs any symbols from it.  By the time it sees the `libmysqlcppconn-static.a` file it has already looked at (and ignored) the libmysqlclient.so library, and doesn't go back to look at it again.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Wakely. I noticed the order is different in the example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html#samplecode), where cc is used, so this ordering is specific to gcc/g++, right?
Anyhow, I'm still getting [(different) errors](http://pastebin.com/4EWNgy9i), so perhaps I'm missing something?