# undefined reference to get_driver_instance - on ubuntu - debian is ok

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I am using c++ mysql connector and when I am compiling on ubnutu 14.04 64bit (g++ 4.8.4), the following error occur:

> ....so: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'

however if I try to compile it on Debian 8 64bit (g++ 4.8.4) it compile without any error...

also if I compile it on ubuntu, but with g++ 5.1 it has no errors...

The command which I run:

> g++-4.9  -std=c++11 -lmysqlcppconn server.cpp -I ./websocketpp/ -L mysql-connector-c++/lib -lboost_system  -lbeanstalkpp -lboost_chrono -I rapidjson/include/

**EDIT:**
the output of compiler with error (using -v switch)

```
g++  -v -std=c++11 server.cpp -I mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/ -I ./websocketpp/ -L mysql-connector-c++/lib -lboost_system -lmysqlcppconn -lbeanstalkpp -lboost_chrono -I rapidjson/include/ -lpthread
[1] 4364
 Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-std=c++11' '-I' 'mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/' '-I' './websocketpp/' '-Lmysql-connector-c++/lib' '-I' 'rapidjson/include/' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -I mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/ -I ./websocketpp/ -I rapidjson/include/ -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE server.cpp -quiet -dumpbase server.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase server -std=c++11 -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/cc8ZjcCL.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/
./websocketpp/
rapidjson/include/
/usr/include/c++/4.8
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
/usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 9cb21c615435621dce26fe5e793192fd
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-std=c++11' '-I' 'mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/' '-I' './websocketpp/' '-Lmysql-connector-c++/lib' '-I' 'rapidjson/include/' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
as -v -I mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/ -I ./websocketpp/ -I rapidjson/include/ --64 -o /tmp/cczJ3S6r.o /tmp/cc8ZjcCL.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-std=c++11' '-I' 'mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/' '-I' './websocketpp/' '-Lmysql-connector-c++/lib' '-I' 'rapidjson/include/' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -Lmysql-connector-c++/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/cczJ3S6r.o -lboost_system -lmysqlcppconn -lbeanstalkpp -lboost_chrono -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
//usr/local/lib/libbeanstalkpp.so: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[1]+  Exit 1                  g++ -v -std=c++11 server.cpp -I mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn/ -I ./websocketpp/ -L mysql-connector-c++/lib -lboost_system -lmysqlcppconn -lbeanstalkpp -lboost_chrono -I rapidjson/include/ -lpthread
```

Comment: Odd indeed. Maybe on Ubuntu, slightly different versions of the libraries are used? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995319/c-mysql-connector-undefined-reference-to-get-driver-instance-already-tri offers some ideas on a similar problem including using a statically linked mysql connector library, checking the connector library for the presence of the symbol with nm, etc.

Comment: What does the verbose output show of the compilation (e.g. `g++ -v`)?

Comment: @0range well the problem is that lib mysqlcppconn was same for both computers, - downloaded same package. I tried also the solution in link which you provided, also in some others... not working...

Comment: @txtechhelp I added output of compilation with -v